# inequality for a family of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose I have two collections of $n$ vectors $\{u_i\}$ and $\{v_i\}$. To be clear, each $u_i$ and $v_i$ is a vector, *not* a component of a vector. Is it true that $$\left|\sum_i^n\langle u_i,v_i\rangle\right|^2\le\left(\sum_i^n\langle u_i,u_i\rangle\right)\left(\sum_j^n\langle v_j,v_j\rangle\right)?$$It may be worth mentioning that the case $n=1$ reduces to Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Define vectors $$U = \begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_n\end{bmatrix},$$
and $$V = \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on $U$ and $V$.

---

Note that
$$\langle U,V \rangle =\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle u_i, v_i \rangle.$$

Comment: Perfect. The pairing you defined on $U$ and $V$ is just the Frobenius inner product on matrices, so using CS in this way is valid. Thank you.